# Multiplicity of G-module

Tags: representation-theory

I am currently working on Bruce Sagan's *The Symmetric Group*.

The following proposition is given without proof:

Let $V$ and $W$ be $G$-modules with $V$ irreducible. Then dim Hom($V$,$W$) is the multiplicity of $V$ in $W$.

---

This proposition is a strengthening of the following corollary of Schur's Lemma:

Let $V$ and $W$ be two $G$-modules with $V$ being irreducible. Then dim Hom($V$,$W$) = $0$ if and only if $W$ contains no submodule isomorphic to $V$.

---

I understand why the corollary is true:

- Let us suppose $W$ contains a submodule isomorphic to $V$. Then clearly, dim Hom($V$,$W$) > $0$ because of the isomorphism from $V$ to the submodule.
- Let us suppose im Hom($V$,$W$) > $0$. Then there must be some non-zero homomorphism from $V$ to some submodule of $W$. As the homomorphism is non-zero, its kernel is not $V$, so the kernel is zero, by Schur's Lemma. Hence it is injective. As it is surjective to its image, it is an isomorphism.

---

How could one prove this proposition? Is the proof similar to the proof of the corollary?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: (I assume you work over $\mathbb{C}$). Are you familiar with the fact that these modules are completely reducible?

Comment: Yes, it's Maschke's Theorem.

Comment: Ok, so do this by induction on the dimension of $W$, using that $\operatorname{Hom}$ is exact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Irreducible Representations and Maschke's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301783/irreducible-representations-and-maschkes-theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $~\hom_G(V,\bigoplus U)=\bigoplus\hom_G(V,U)$

Comment: Much neater than the way I hinted at in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let us write $W \cong mV \oplus m_1 W^{(1)} \oplus m_2 W^{(2)} \oplus ... \oplus m_kW^{(k)}$.
Then

\begin{equation} \text{dim Hom}(V,W) = \text{dim Hom}(V, mV \oplus m_1 W^{(1)} \oplus m_2 W^{(2)} \oplus ... \oplus m_kW^{(k)}) = \end{equation}

\begin{equation} m\cdot\text{dim Hom}(V,V) + m_1\cdot\text{dim Hom}(V,W^{(1)}) + m_2\cdot\text{dim Hom}(V,W^{(2)}) + ... + m_k\cdot\text{dim Hom}(V,W^{(k)}) \end{equation}

But as $V$ and $W^{(i)}$ is inequivalent for any $i$, $\text{dim Hom}(V,W^{(i)}) = 0$ by the corollary I provided above.

Hence $\text{dim Hom}(V,W) = m\cdot\text{dim Hom}(V,V)$. As $V$ is irreducible, $\text{dim Hom}(V,V) = 1$, so

\begin{equation} \text{dim Hom}(V,W) = m.\end{equation}

Is this done right?

How can one prove that $~\hom_G(V,\bigoplus U)=\bigoplus\hom_G(V,U)$?

Thank you very much again!

Comment: That's correct. Have you tried proving $\hom_G(V,\bigoplus U)\cong\bigoplus\hom_G(V,U)$? It shouldn't be too hard to spot what the isomorphism is, then you just have to prove it is one...